# Как не выходить за нижний край экрана?

Tags: python, pygame

Я сделал боковое перемещение корабля посередине слева, и он у меня перемещается во всех направлениях, но выходит за нижний край экрана. Как это решить

```
import sys

from time import sleep

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from game_stats import GameStats

from ship import Ship

from bullet import Bullet

from alien import Alien

from star import Star

from random import randint

from drop import Drop

from game_over import GameOver

from button import Button

#from rectangle import Rectangle

class AlienInvasion:
    """Класс для управления ресурсами и поведением игры."""

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        #self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        #    (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        # Создание экземпляра для хранения игровой статистики.
        #self.stats = GameStats(self)

        #self.game_over = GameOver(self)
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.stars = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.drops = pygame.sprite.Group()

        #self._create_fleet()
        self._create_stars()

        # Создание кнопки Play.
        #self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")


    def run_game(self):
        """Запуск основного цикла игры."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            #if self.stats.game_active:
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_screen()
            #self._update_aliens()
            #self.rectangle.update()
            #self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Обрабатывает нажатия клавиш и события мыши."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self.check_keydown_events(event)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self.check_keyup_events(event)

            #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            #    self._check_play_button(mouse_pos)

    #def start_game(self):
    #        # Сброс игровой статистики.
    #    if self.play_button and not self.stats.game_active:
    #        self.stats.reset_stats()
    #        self.stats.game_active = True

    #        # Очистка списков пришельцев и снарядов.
    #        self.aliens.empty()
    #        self.bullets.empty()

    #        # Создание нового флота и размещение корабля в центре.
    #        self._create_fleet()
    #        self.ship.center_ship()

    #        # Указатель мыши скрывается.
    #        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    #def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
    #    """Запускает новую игру при нажатии кнопки Play."""
    #    button_clicked = self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    #    if button_clicked and not self.stats.game_active:
    #        # Сброс игровой статистики.
    #        self.stats.reset_stats()
    #        self.stats.game_active = True
#
    #        # Очистка списков пришельцев и снарядов.
    #        self.aliens.empty()
    #        self.bullets.empty()
#
    #        # Создание нового флота и размещение корабля в центре.
    #        #self._create_fleet()
    #        self.ship.center_ship()
#
    #        # Указатель мыши скрывается.
    #        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    def check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Реагирует на нажатие клавиш."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            self.ship.moving_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            self.ship.moving_down = True
        #elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
        #    self.start_game()

    def check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Реагирует на отпускание клавиш."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            self.ship.moving_left = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            self.ship.moving_up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            self.ship.moving_down = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Создание нового снаряда и включение его в группу bullets."""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Обновляет позиции снарядов и уничтожает старые снаряды."""
        # Обновление позиций снарядов.
        self.bullets.update()

        # Удаление снарядов, вышедших за край экрана.
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.right >= self.settings.screen_width:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

        self._check_bullet_alien_collisions()

    def _check_bullet_alien_collisions(self):
        """Обработка коллизий снарядов с пришельцами."""
        # Удаление снарядов и пришельцев, участвующих в коллизиях.
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.aliens, False, True)

        if not self.aliens:
            # Уничтожение существующих снарядов и создание нового флота.
            self.bullets.empty()
            self._create_fleet()

    def _update_aliens(self):
        """Обновляет позиции всех пришельцев во флоте."""
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()

        # Проверка коллизий "пришелец — корабль".
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
            self._ship_hit()

        # Проверить, добрались ли пришельцы до нижнего края экрана.
        self._check_aliens_bottom()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Создание флота вторжения."""
        # Создание пришельца и вычисление количества пришельцев в ряду
        # Интервал между соседними пришельцами равен ширине пришельца.
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

        """Определяет количество рядов, помещающихся на экране."""
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_width) - ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

        # Создание флота вторжения.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)


    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        """Создание пришельца и размещение его в ряду."""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = self.settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        alien.rect.y = alien.y
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """Реагирует на достижение пришельцем края экрана."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        """Опускает весь флот и меняет направление флота."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

    def _ship_hit(self):
        """Обрабатывает столкновение корабля с пришельцем."""
        if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
            # Уменьшение ships_left.
            self.stats.ships_left -= 1

            # Очистка списков пришельцев и снарядов.
            self.aliens.empty()
            self.bullets.empty()

            # Создание нового флота и размещение корабля в центре.
            self._create_fleet()
            #self.ship.center_ship()

            # Пауза.
            sleep(0.5)
        else:
            self.stats.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    def _check_aliens_bottom(self):
        """Проверяет, добрались ли пришельцы до нижнего края экрана."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.rect.bottom <= screen_rect.bottom:
                # Происходит то же, что при столкновении с кораблем.
                self._ship_hit()
                break

    def _create_stars(self):
        """Создание звезд."""
        # Создание звезды и вычисление количества звезд в ряду
        # Интервал между соседними звездами равен ширине звезды.
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width + (10 * star_width)
        number_star_x = available_space_x // (10 * star_width)

        """Определяет количество рядов, помещающихся на экране."""
        available_space_y = self.settings.screen_height + (10 * star_width)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (10 * star_width)

        # Создание звезд.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for star_number in range(number_star_x):
                self._create_star(star_number, row_number, random_number=randint(-1, 1))

    def _create_star(self, star_number, row_number, random_number):
        """Создание звезды и размещение его в ряду."""
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        star.x = star_width + 10 * star_width * star_number * random_number
        star.rect.x = star.x
        star.rect.y = star.rect.height + 10 * star.rect.height * row_number * random_number
        self.stars.add(star)

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Обновляет изображения на экране и отображает новый экран."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        #self.game_over.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.stars.draw(self.screen)
        #self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
        #self.rectangle.draw_rectangle()
        self.ship.blitme()
        # Кнопка Play отображается в том случае, если игра неактивна.
        #if not self.stats.game_active:
        #    self.play_button.draw_button()

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Создание экземпляра и запуск игры.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()


import pygame
class Ship():
    """Класс для управления кораблем."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Инициализирует корабль и задает его начальную позицию."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Загружает изображение корабля и получает прямоугольник.
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")

        # Масштабируем изображение
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (80, 80))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle=-90)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Каждый новый корабль появляется у нижнего края экрана.
        self.rect.midleft = self.screen_rect.midleft
        #self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        # Сохранение вещественной координаты центра корабля.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        # Флаг перемещения
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

        # Получить значение космического корабля, перемещенного вниз
        self.screen_rect.top = self.rect.top


    def update(self):
        """Обновляет позицию корабля с учетом флага."""
         #Обновляется атрибут x, не rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed

        if self.moving_down and self.rect.midleft < self.screen_rect.midleft:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.midleft > self.screen_rect.midleft:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed

        # Обновление атрибута rect на основании self.x.
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def blitme(self):
        """Рисует корабль в текущей позиции."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы изменил метод update и разделил на 3 метода.

Назовем их: `_moving_ship_x()`, `_moving_ship_y()`,moving_ship().

Теперь код этих методов (Подставлять эти методы в основной класс будешь сам):

```
def _moving_ship_x(self):
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.x += self.ship_speed
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

    self.rect.x = self.x

def _moving_ship_y(self):
    if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
        self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
    if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
        self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
    
    self.y = self.rect.y

def moving_ship(self):
    self._moving_ship_y()
    self._moving_ship_x()
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: спасибо вам!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте метод `update` класса `Ship` таким:

```py
    def update(self):
        """Обновляет позицию корабля с учетом флага."""
         #Обновляется атрибут x, не rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed

        if self.moving_down and self.rect.midleft < self.screen_rect.midleft:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.midleft > self.screen_rect.midleft:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed

        # Обновление атрибута rect на основании self.x.
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

Comment: ничего не вышло, также выходит за край. Но еще проблема возникла в том, что теперь я не могу поднять корабль. Но я уже смог решить эту проблему, а проблему с выходим за нижний край экрана нет

Comment: @Rauf 44, изменил код, попробуйте теперь

Comment: не вышло, также выходит за край экрана

Comment: @Rauf 44, поменял флаги местами, теперь попробуйте